# windows phone api to access built in alarm

Tags: windows-phone-7, alarm

Is there any api to access the alarm settings of a windows phone 7 device. I am not looking for creating new alarms, but access settings of the default alarm app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is not. If you know 7.0 well, you can check out new functionality that was added in 7.1 to see if what you want has been added:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637516(v=VS.92).aspx